# In struts2, how to use annotaion to validate a modeldriven action?

Tags: java, struts2

I want to use annotation to validate my action.

but the data is located in a model (because the modeldriven interface), So I cannot annotation the action fields.

So, How can I annotation the "Model"'s fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use annotations by using `@VisitorFieldValidator` on your overridden `getModel()` method.

```
@Override
@VisitorFieldValidator(appendPrefix = false)
public Object getModel() {
    return yourBean;
}
```

Now do the normal validations using annotation.